# Which PC to choose for my studies?

Tags: pc, windows, performance

I'm going to study informatics at the University. For this I want to choose a computer that is able to deal with the necessities there and is fast. I scanned the internet and stepped into the zbook series of HP. Now my question is whether HP ZBook 17 G3 or 15 G3 fulfill my requirements since I also want to use it for writing and dictating in Microsoft Office. What do you think according to the description I gave or are their other informations you need? Do you have any model recommendations for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are a bit OP for studying informatics (I use an upgraded hp probook 650 g1). If you can get an Asus VivoBook 15 with an intel core i5 and 16GB of ram, that will be more than enough. Most times, you don't need a fast gpu, but a decent cpu, ssd and RAM are needed, and thats what that laptop has. A low price is also good for students, and this one costs about half of those zbooks.